# C++ trouble with pointers to objects

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I have a class with a vector of pointers to objects. I've introduced some elements on this vector, and on my main file I've managed to print them and add others with no problems. Now I'm trying to remove an element from that vector and check to see if it's not NULL but it is not working.

I'm filling it with on class Test:

```
Other *a = new Other(1,1);
Other *b = new Other(2,2);
Other *c = new Other(3,3);

v->push_back(a);
v->push_back(b);
v->push_back(c);
```

And on my main file I have:

```
Test t;
(...)

Other *pointer = t.vect->at(0);

delete t.vect->at(0);
t.vect->erase(t.vect->begin());

if (pointer == NULL) { cout << "Nothing here.."; } // Never enters here..
```

Comment: you just have to set the pointer to NULL right after you delete it. it might seem redundant, but it isn't. delete frees the memory, setting it to NULL let's you check that it has been deleted.

Comment: @zxcvbnm: that's a good practice, but it won't work in this case. Zibd has two pointers pointing to the same object; using one of them to delete the object and then setting it to NULL still leaves the other pointing to freed memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deletion of memory pointed by a pointer, doesn't set the pointer to NULL.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting a pointer doesn't have to zero it, it just frees the memory assigned there. Using `pointer` is undefined after the delete though, as the memory is free to be used for other things. Technically the C++ spec intentionally leaves it up to implementations whether they want to zero a deleted pointer or not, but practically none that I know of do so

Comment: Right. In that case is there any way so I can do what I pretend?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, what's the point of that check?

Comment: Anyway note that the pointer in the vector is deleted, but it's a completely different copy of the same address which is checked. No way is the C++ runtime going to search your entire program for every copy of the address, and set them all to null.

Answer (score 1):

You set pointer equal to the address of something, and never touched it again, so of course it won't be null. The fact that you then did something to the object is irrelevant.

Using simple pointers, there is no safe way for pointer to determine whether the object it once pointed to has been deleted. The simplest way to do what you seem to want to do is by leaving it to the containers: if you're interested in that object, search for pointer in the vector to see whether it's still there (and don't delete the object without erasing the corresponding element from the vector, or you'll have the same problem all over again).

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the checking a deleted ptr problem you could use [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

Instead of delete use `.reset()` and to check if the ptr is still valid use `.get()`
(Actually you can just use `if(p)` where p is the shared_ptr because it has a conversion to bool)